# Where to put required behavior on close in Python

Tags: python, class, constructor, resources, destructor

I have a class that creates a temporary file on construction and should remove it once it is finished. Note that I understand creating a temporary file may not be the ideal solution to the original problem but assume that that cannot be changed. Along with that, the code will run multiple times throughout the course of the program.

Which is the most ideal place to delete the file?

**Option 1:**

```
import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open("temp.txt", 'wb')

    def do_something(self):
        # ...

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
        os.remove("temp.txt")
while True:
    foo = Foo()

    foo.do_something()
    foo.close()
```

**Option 2:**

```
import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open("temp.txt", 'wb')

    def do_something(self):
        # ...

    def __del__(self):
        self.file.close()
        os.remove("temp.txt")
while True:
    with Foo() as foo:
        foo.do_something()
```

I'm hesitant to use option 2 because I've heard it is a bad practice to put required actions in the destructor. However, option 2 seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to make sure that the file is gone when the program closes, then you should use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module. In other cases, you should always use option 1 for the reasons outlined in [this article.](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python)

Comment: By the way, I've updated the main post to reflect that the file must be removed before the code continues.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you were using with statements, oops.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) and you should put the file deletion in the `__exit__` method. You are already using the `with` statement, it's just that the class you have defined won't work with it since it lacks the required `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.